# How to change MSSQL Port from 1433 to 1533 in Linux. My hosting provider has blocked the port 1433 in their network

Tags: linux, sql-server

How to change MSSQL Port from 1433 to 1533 in Centos. My hosting provider has blocked the port 1433 in their network.

> > I have installed the MSSQL with this command.
> >
> > sudo yum install -y mssql-server
> >
> > Configuration file is at opt/mssql/bin/mssql-conf setup
>
> I want to access it with ServerIPAddress,1533 from management studio
>   out side of server.

Comment: you should change your hosting provider.

Comment: Appears to be a duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29866204/how-to-change-the-default-port-of-mysql-from-3306-to-3360

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following command has fixed my issue.

> sudo /opt/mssql/bin/mssql-conf set tcpport 1533
>
> sudo systemctl restart mssql-server
>
> sudo firewall-cmd --zone=public --add-port=1533/tcp --permanent
>
> sudo firewall-cmd --reload